# Criar sessão em https com requisição ajax http

Tags: ajax, session, http, https

Eu estou desenvolvendo um site onde o lado cliente acessa inicialmente http até fazer o login. O login é feito do próprio http com uma requisição ajax que chama o script php em https e neste script é criada uma $_SESSION com os dados do usuário. Retornando ok do script login.php, a função javascript redireciona a página para o https onde a sessão fora criada, porém, o script index.php não encontra a sessão criada. Fiz vários testes e só consigo sucesso se a $_SESSION for criada numa requisição direta do https e não por ajax. Configurei o CORS no servidor e está funcionando perfeitamente.
o javascript do http está assim:

```
$.post("https://www.dominio.com/login.php", $(form).serialize(), function (data) {
    if ((data.code === PSYS.CONST.STT_OK) && (data.data.https_admin)) {
        window.location = data.data.https_admin;
    }; // else mensagem de erro
}, 'json');
```

O script login.php faz basicamente o seguinte:

```
// ler o dados do usuário no banco de dados e armazena no array result
$result = getDataFromUser($user, $password);
if ($result[code]) {
   $_SESSION['Login'] = $result['data'];
}
return json_encode($result);
```

Então o java script redireciona o site para o https://www.dominio.com/index.php que faz o seguinte:

```
if (!session_id()):
    session_start();
endif;
if (!isset($_SESSION['Login'])):
    // se a sessão não existir
    header("location: http://www.domini.com/index.php");
endif;
```

Se em em vez de fazer a requisição ajax para o servidor e a action do form for diretamente para o https no submit ele cria a sessão normalmente, mas isto gera um efeito que que não quero no site, até mesmo porque é um site de tecnologia, e, comportamentos padronizados serão amplamente utilizados no site principal (http), e é muito importante que ele respeite o que está em http e o que está em https. Não existe nenhuma requisição a banco de dados em http, todo acesso ao banco de dados é feito no https.
Obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Oi pessoal achei a resposta ao meu problema em:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441496/session-lost-when-switching-from-http-to-https-in-php

Obrigado.